# Custom memory manager with thread local storage

Tags: c++, c

There is a custom memory manager in our program, all of our malloc/free calls are managed by the memory manager, but in the initial of the program getpwuid() will be call and  in some customers' machine with nss_ldap activated it will call the malloc from libc not from our memory manager which leads to an error in our memory manager, the stack report from gdb is:

```
Breakpoint 2, 0x0000003df8cc6eb0 in brk () from /lib64/libc.so.6
0  0x0000003df8cc6eb0 in brk () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1  0x0000003df8cc6f72 in sbrk () from /lib64/libc.so.6
2  0x0000003df8c73d29 in __default_morecore () from /lib64/libc.so.6
3  0x0000003df8c70090 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
4  0x0000003df8c70c9d in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
5  0x0000003df880fc65 in __tls_get_addr () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
6  0x00002aaaae302a7c in _nss_ldap_inc_depth () from /lib64/libnss_ldap.so.2
7  0x00002aaaae2f91a4 in _nss_ldap_enter () from /lib64/libnss_ldap.so.2
8  0x00002aaaae2f942c in _nss_ldap_getbyname () from /lib64/libnss_ldap.so.2
9  0x00002aaaae2f9aa9 in _nss_ldap_getpwuid_r () from /lib64/libnss_ldap.so.2
10 0x0000003df8c947c5 in getpwuid_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
11 0x0000003df8c9412f in getpwuid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
12 0x0000000001414be3 in lc_username ()
```

I've traced the code of _nss_ldap_inc_depth(), it seems the __tls_get_addr() got call because the thread local storage is used, I've try to change the memory manager to shared library but the __tls_get_addr() still call the malloc from libc, how can I made it call our memory manager instead of libc's ??

Comment: looks like the problem originates from `lc_username()` can you post that code ?

Comment: I think it is not because of lc_username(), I made a direct call to getpwuid() and got the same results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LD_PRELOAD` to load your library before any other library (including glibc) and it will be linked instead, something like:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/library/libmymalloc.so /bin/myprog
```

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23) that shows how it works, it even has an example interposed `malloc`

Comment: I've try LD_PRELOAD but it still calls the malloc from libc :(

Comment: I think the reason that it didn't work is beacuse of __tls_get_addr()

Comment: @DreamLinuxer as a side note, you shouldn't be calling `getpwuid()` you should use the re-entrant version `getpwuid_r()`

Comment: lc_username() comes from third-party, we only link its static library.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your memory manager to use `mmap` instread of `brk`.

There can be only one user of `brk` in a process. So if you haven't replaced all calls to `malloc` and related functions (`calloc`, `strdup` and more), you must not use `brk`.

`mmap`, however, has no such problems. Your memory manager can use `mmap`, and `malloc` can still work in parallel.

Comment: The memory manager is legacy code, I really don't want to modifiy it. I prefer to workaround this by replacing malloc in __tls_get_addr().

Comment: I don't think replacing `malloc` calls one by one is a good idea - you'll keep finding new ones. You need to find a way replace all calls automatically (lots of software packages, such as Valgrind, do it).

Comment: It runs fine in valgrind which means the malloc call is replaced correctly under valgrind @@"

Comment: If Valgrind can replace all `malloc` calls, so can you.